# Form Creation on Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, formwizard

I have been struggling with this and if anyone has any ideas on how to accomplish this, I would be greatful.  I have a database that has three tables:

Table Buildings:

```
ID|Build Name
-------------
1|Home
2|Office
3|Shed
```

Table Costs:

```
ID|Cost Name
-------------
1|Electricity
2|Water
3|Sewage
4|Maintenance
```

Table Cost By Site Per a Month:

```
ID|Date|Building ID|Cost ID|Avg Pct
___________________________________
```

I want to create a form that allows me to populate based on a single date all the possible costs by building.  Therefore the form, for this database would be:

```
date: Enter Date
building:  [Drop Down Box for Building Selection]
_________________________________________________
Electricity: Avg Pct USER BOX TO ENTER
Water:       Avg Pct USER BOX TO ENTER
Sewage:      Avg Pct USER BOX TO ENTER
Maintenance: Avg Pct USER BOX TO ENTER
```

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks!
Jon

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new form based on the third table you listed. My first question is: does it HAVE to be displayed the way you show above? The reason I ask this is because you can simplify your development by adding a datasheet view on the form based on the third table and have the user simply add the rows to this table, row by row.

For example:

Date | Building combo box | Costs combo box | Avg Pct textbox.

And the user will enter the data one row at a time.
Make sure you create an index on Date/BuildingId/CostId so that you cannot have multiple values for the same Date/Building/Cost instance.

If you really have to display it the way you show above, then you need to make sure your form is not based on any table and have a button do the insert using VBA. For example, the button will simple take the values provided by the user and generate a SQL statement (an INSERT statement) that will add a new record into that third table.